# Inserting data into mysql DB with cakePHP

Tags: php, mysql, database, cakephp, insert

I have what should be a simply problem to solve, I have data that needs to be inserted into my DB for exporting to CSV in the future however standard PHP code is not working for me, I have tried the following line with no luck:

```
$insertQuery = ("INSERT INTO `DBNAME`.`TABLENAME` (`1`, `2`, `3`, `4`, `5`, `6`, `7`) VALUES ('{$1}', '{$2}', '{$3}', '{$cityquery['city']}', '{$cityquery['regionName']}', '{$cityquery ['country']}', '{$lang}')");
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: You need to provide more information - your code just shows a string, no database functions

Comment: Please try adding `echo $insertQuery;` immediately after you declare it, and paste it here to help us understand the problem.

Comment: Added that and received the following information:          INSERT INTO `DBNAME`.`TABLENAME` (`1`, `2`, `3`, `4`, `5`, `6`, `7`) VALUES ('1', '2', '3', 'city', 'state', 'country', 'en')

Comment: Which version of CakePHP are you using? CakePHP 3 has a very different approach to dealing with the database to CakePHP 2.

Answer (score 4):

G'day Steve,

May I ask as to why you are using SQL in CakePHP?

CakePHP uses Models and an ORM approach to managing data. Which can be found here: http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/models.html

I'll assume you're using V2 because that is the one I'm proficient with.

CakePHP enforces you to call your database table names in plural form and your Model Classes in Singular (For example)

```
Database table name = users,
Model i.e (Class) name = User
```

Now when you want to save data to User, we simply use CakePHP's ORM

```
$this->User->save(); //Now, assume we want to add a new record, we simply do:
$this->User->save(array('first_name' => 'Melon', 'last_name' => 'Head'));
```

If we wanted to edit an existing record, there are a few ways to approach it. One example is:

```
$this->User->id = 1;
$this->User->save(array('email' => 'melon.head@yahoo.com'));
```

OR the one I use

```
$this->User->save(array('id' => 1, 'email' => 'melon.head@yahoo.com'));
```

I hope this answers your question :)

I'll extend it a little more. You mentioned the table name is 'assessments'. Therefore, in our 'app/Model' folder in CakePHP we'd create a php file called Assessment.php inside the file we have:

```
class Assessment extends AppModel{}
```

That is the first step, to connect to the DB, there is a file in 'app/Config/database.php'. When we open this file, we'll see an array:

```
public $default = array(
    'datasource' => 'Database/Mysql',
    'persistent' => false,
    'host' => 'localhost',
    'login' => 'mysql_user',
    'password' => 'da_password',
    'database' => 'the_db_name',
    'encoding' => 'utf8'
);
```

Setup this array so it can connect to the db.

Now we go to the Controller. I'll assume you have a Controller setup called AssessmentController.php if you don't thats ok we'll fix that shortly.

In the Controller, we setup a function that will save our data for example

```
public function index(){
      //Here we'll save the data
      //I'll assume also you know where $1 is coming from.
      //Data from the user comes through the array var $this->request->data
     $this->Assessment->save(
            array(
                 '1' => "{$1}"
            )
     );
}
```

If you have a different controller name setup, that's ok. CakePHP automatically connects Same Model and Controller names together in the above example we have Assessment Controller and Assessment Model

If we have a different controller for example the controller is called Student, well we simply add an array to the controller called $uses

```
public $uses = array('Assessment');
```

This will tell CakePHP 'Hey I need this Model'. CakePHP responds 'Here you go'.

Comment: I also forgot to mention, I hope that data in your INSERT string is sanitized before it is used. You should also use Bound parameters for heightened security

Comment: You can still do that with The ORM by going $this->TABLENAME->save(array('1' => "{$1}", '2' => "{$2}")) and so forth. Of course, make sure you have the Model setup

Comment: The reason for using this is because people are going to fill out a form and the data is transmitted but the results are in the forms of 1, 2, 3, 4 to corresponding multiple choice answers on the form. The database name in this case is assessments, I am guessing I only need 2 lines of code, one to identify the DB in this case assessments and another to upload the data. I don't get how the lines should be written. This is my first time using cakePHP and while I had no issues having it send the email with a little research this has got me stumped.  Thanks Again

Comment: ok that clears up "line 2" but how does one setup a model and what exactly is the purpose in doing so? I basically just want to write, $this->assessements->save(array('1' => "{$1}", '2' => "{$2}"))... but you are saying there is a line above this which is necessary which I don't understand.

Comment: I extended my answer above, hopefully that should help you further.
CakePHP uses the popular MVC approach.

Comment: Thanks for the advice Tim, I think that what is not making sense to me is the "Model" and I will do some reading on that shortly to try to get a better understanding of how the Model and the Controller work.

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Model%E2%80%93view%E2%80%93controller

Hopefully the above link should explain it better than I can. Essentially the Model is the PHP connecter to the db table through a process called Object Relational Mapping. Which is basically a layer that sits between the DB and the PHP. To manipulate the data in the DB, you talk to the ORM and to access the ORM, you go through the Model. In your example the Assessment is the Model.